# Return several partial views within a main view, based on actions in the partial views

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax

I have this view based on person model which is an entity model.

```
@model TestApp.Models.Person

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

@Html.Partial("../PersonContactData/Create");
```

Then My PersonContactData controller returns the partial view "Create" which has a form and a submit button. When I press that submit button I do a redirectToAction to Index from the PersonContactData controller and I want to return the view from Index to the page described above.

How Do I do that?

And I want all this to happen without the page refreshing. I can pass all values with ajax but I need some 'container' or something to actually take the partial views (list, create, edit,.. from PersonContactData) that are being returned to the main view which is based on Person model.
In other words that the actions, their corresponding partial views and their functionality can work within a page that is based on another model (Person) and controller (PersonController)

This is for example an ajax post function I used to get the values from the create view. This works, but still I want to redirect to action Index in my HttpPost Create action and return the View for Index, as it should work. But my main View (based on Person model) won't display it.

```
function ACGetList() {
        var personContactData = {
            ContactType: $('#ddlContactDataType').val(),
            Value: $('#txtContactDataValue').val()
        };
        $.ajax({
            url: '/PersonContactData/Create',
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify(personContactData),
            dataType: 'Json',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function () { },
            error: function () { }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

OK as far as I know.

An MVC system is a serverside structure or frame work.
M=Model, V=View,C=Controller.

Models are validations, db etc,
View are markups,json,css,xml etc...
Controllers, are php,asp, so u can say what to show when.

As far as I understand your question you are simply just asking use ajax.

What ajax does is requests a page and retruns some data or all of it to the main page using js.
Check out `jQuery .ajax` function or google it.

**so lets say ur home page is:**

`mysite.com` returns `<h1>Hello World!</h1>`

**Then ajax page has**
`<p>I am ajax</p>`

then on home page using js/jq you can tell where you want "i am ajax" to go to

Comment: In my project I use ajax to get Partial View 'Create'(based on model PersonContactData) wich is inserted into my main View(based on model Person). But Still If I click on the button (onclick function ACGetList is displayed now in main topic) from the partial view I want my RedirectToAction function to return another partial view to the main page (based on Person model)

Comment: ok on ur ajax success you can have another ajax into it or use queue function to happen just after it, if ur redirecting it on server side, ur just forcing a browser to go to a different location. Download firebug, on ur firefox, it will help you understand it better and debug your script properly then you can see what each ajax request is returning.